# Need help creating a function for an angle

Tags: functions

Help with creating functions.

I have an assignment I need to do, and the first part is asking me to create a one argument function that has one angle between 0 and 2pi. Ok, I get that. But then it says that the function will create a line from the origin to the point in the unit circle at that angle. I know I’m totally overthinking this. Do I define the function as
f[x_]:={Cos[x], Sin[x]}? Or do I simply need to do something like f[x_]=:x Degree? Or do I need to try something else? I ended up trying it out with cosx, sinx by making a table using the function from 0 to 360 in steps of 3.6 (I need 100 uniform numbers in the interval 0-2pi). This, of course, when plotted just left me with a circle outlined in the x,y coordinates that were defined by the function.
I need an angle (not coordinates) and I need the function to give me a line coming from the origin.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE! To be honest this seems to be rather a mathematics question than a Mathematica one. As you noted `{Cos[x], Sin[x]}` never crosses the origin. You say you want to keep the angle fixed. What is `x` in your parametrization? Do you know about polar coordinates? What is varying in a "line through the origin at a fixed angle"?

Comment: I looked into polar coordinates....does this mean I should define my function by the Pythagorean theorem and use tan to get the angle?

Comment: `Graphics[{Blue, Circle[], Red, Line[AnglePath[{{2, 60 Degree}}]]}]`

Comment: As a parametric line `Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[t*{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  Epilog -> Circle[]]
 , {{\[Theta], 0.1}, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]` or in non-parametric `Manipulate[
 Plot[Tan[\[Theta]] x, {x, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Epilog -> Circle[]]
 , {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`

Comment: A function that gives you the x and y coordinates of a straight line is e.g. x {Sin[phi],Cos[phi]} for a fixed value of phi